# chaining ngResource $promise success and errors

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angular-promise, ngresource

I'd like to know if it's possible to handle the `$promise` returned by ngResource on multiple levels so that the code is DRY

here is a simple example

```
aService = function(aResource) {
  var error, success;
  success = function(response) {
    console.log('Service Success');
  };
  error = function(response) {
    console.log('Service Error');
  };

  this.servicePostReq = function() {
    return aResource.save().$promise.then(success, error);
  };
  return this;

angular.module('app.service').factory('aService', ['aResource', aService]);
```

this works fine so far... it `Service Success` when response is OK and it `Service Error` when response is not OK

but when I add a controller that use this `aService` like following

```
aController = function(aService) {
  var error, success;
  success = function(response) {
    console.log('Controller Success');
  };
  error = function(response) {
    console.log('Controller Error');
  };
  this.controllerPostReq = function() {
    aService.servicePostReq().then(success, error);
  };

  return this;
};

angular.module('app.controller').controller('aController', ['aService', aController]);
```

the controller always success...

so if the request return success the output is

```
Service Success
Controller Success
```

and if the request fails the output is

```
Service Error
Controller Success
```

how do I chain the promise so that I don't have to add the code handled in the service for every controller that use the service ?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your service. Change this:

```
  this.servicePostReq = function() {
    return aResource.save().$promise.then(success, error);
  };
```

To this:

```
  this.servicePostReq = function() {
    return aResource.save().$promise.then(success);
  };
```

**Explanation:**

Since your service returns `aResource.save().$promise.then(success, error)`, it's returning a new promise with an error handler included. Later, in your controller, you add onto the chain like this.

```
aService.servicePostReq().then(success, error);
```

The complete promise chain at this point looks if you expand it out:

```
return aResource.save().$promise
  .then(successFnFromService, errorFnFromService)
  .then(successFnFromController, errorFnFromController);
```

Since you catch the error from `aResource.save()` with `errorFnFromService`, the promise chain is basically "clean" at this point and it will just continue with the next `then`.

By removing the first error handler, you allow the error to be caught later on.

A better way (in general) to handle errors in promise chains would be to use a single .catch() at the end of the chain.

Consider this bad code (try running on your browser console):

```
new Promise(
  function(resolve, reject){
    reject('first');
  }).then(
    function(result) {
      console.log('1st success!', result);
      return result;
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log('1st error!', err);
      return err;
    }
  ).then(
    function(result){
      console.log('2nd success!', result);
    },
    function(err){
      console.log("2nd error!", err);
    }
  );
```

Output:

```
1st error! first
2nd success! first
```

Better way:

```
new Promise(
  function(resolve, reject){
    reject('first');
  }).then(function(result) {
    console.log('1st success!', result);
    return result;
  }).then(function(result){
    console.log('2nd success!', result);
  // catch error once at the end
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log("error!", err);
  });
```

Output:

```
error! first
```

Try both of those in browser console, and change `reject` to `resolve` to see how it affects the output.

Answer (score 1):

add a dependency on the `$q` and use `$q.reject` to control the execution...

in your example you need a `$q.reject` in the `aService.error` method

as mentioned [here in the $q docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

> `reject(reason);`
>
> Creates a promise that is resolved as rejected with the specified reason. This api should be used to forward rejection in a chain of promises. If you are dealing with the last promise in a promise chain, you don't need to worry about it.
>
> When comparing deferreds/promises to the familiar behavior of try/catch/throw, think of reject as the throw keyword in JavaScript. This also means that if you "catch" an error via a promise error callback and you want to forward the error to the promise derived from the current promise, you have to "rethrow" the error by returning a rejection constructed via reject.

Answer (score 1):

To properly chain promises, both success and error handlers should return some value. The return values are automatically wrapped in a new promise for you. This means that in the case of errors, you must return a rejected promise using `$q.reject`.

So your service should look like this:

```
aService = function($q, aResource) {
  var error, success;
  success = function(response) {
    // important! return a value, handlers down the chain will
    // execute their success handlers and receive this value
    return 'Service Success';
  };
  error = function(response) {
    // important! return a REJECTION, handlers down the chain will
    // execute their error handlers and receive this value
    return $q.reject('Service Error');
  };

  this.servicePostReq = function() {
    return aResource.save().$promise.then(success, error);
  };
  return this;

angular.module('app.service').factory('aService', ['$q', 'aResource', aService]);
```

Comment: While I agree with most of your answer, I'm confused as to why the aService.success method does not use $q.resolve() but aService.error uses $q.reject().

Comment: This still won't work. The reason is because `aResource.save().$promise.then(success, error)`, is both thenable and contains an error handler. Any .then statements chained onto there will run regardless of if there is an error or not. Example in [this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/S0UJvE2CJlWcqlLqs23X?p=preview) (open console to see output).